# Dispaly a Pop message from controller to view without refreshing the whole page

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am a beginner using MVC4 and Entity framework 5. What i am trying to do is check wheather the acctCode entered by user exist in database or not and give an pop msg to the view if the acctCode exists. what i tried is..

My controller code

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(AccountCode accountcode)
    {
        int count = db.AccountCodes.Count(model => model.acctCode==accountcode.acctCode);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (count == 1)
            {
                TempData["msg"] = "<script>alert('Account Code already exist');</script>";
            }
            else
            {
                db.AccountCodes.Add(accountcode);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }

        ViewBag.clusterAcct = new SelectList(db.ClusterAccounts, "clusterAcct", "description", accountcode.clusterAcct);
        return View(accountcode);
    }
```

My View

```
    @model MvcRome.Models.AccountCode

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>

@Html.Raw(TempData["msg"])


@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "AccountCodes", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl },new AjaxOptions{HttpMethod="Post"}, new { @class = "bootstrap-frm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Account</legend>
    <br />

   <table>
       <tr>
           <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.acctCode)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.acctCode)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.shortCode)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.shortCode, new { style = "width:50px" })
            </td>
           <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.shortCode)</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> 
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.acctCode)</td>
     </tr>
</table>


    <fieldset>
        <legend >Groups</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>

                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.groups, "Parts", new { id = "Parts", @onClick = "grpPartsTaxClick();", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                    @Html.Label("Parts", "Parts", new { style = "padding-right:20px" })
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.groups, "Labor", new { id = "Labor", @onClick = "grpLaborClick();", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                    @Html.Label("Labor", "Labor", new { style = "padding-right:20px" })
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.groups, "Tax", new { id = "Tax", @onClick = "grpPartsTaxClick();", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                    @Html.Label("Tax", "Tax", new { style = "padding-right:20px" })
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.groups, "Other", new { @checked = "checked", id = "Other", @onClick = "grpOtherClick();", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                    @Html.Label("Other", "Other", new { style = "padding-right:20px" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.groups)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>      

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend >Group Type</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>

                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.groupType, "None", new { @checked = "checked", id = "GTNone", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                    @Html.Label("GTNone", "None", new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.groupType, "Labor", new { id = "GTLabor", @disabled = true, @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                    @Html.Label("GTLabor", "Labor", new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.groupType, "Refinishing", new { id = "GTRefinishing", @disabled = true, @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                    @Html.Label("GTRefinishing", "Refinishing", new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.groupType, "Sublet", new { id = "GTSublet", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                    @Html.Label("GTSublet", "Sublet", new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.groupType, "Miscellaneous", new { id = "GTMiscellaneous", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                    @Html.Label("GTMiscellaneous", "Miscellaneous", new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.groupType)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>   
    </fieldset>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.descrp)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.descrp)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.descrp)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.shortDescrp)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.shortDescrp)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.shortDescrp)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>   
    <div id="tabs">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Accounts Default</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Cluster Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Quick Books/Acc Pac</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-4">ERA Accounts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-5">Schedule/Forecasting</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <table>
                <tr>

                    <td style="white-space:nowrap">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ADBalanceAcct)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ADBalanceAcct)
                    </td>

                    <td  style="white-space:nowrap">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ADLaborOpt)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ADLaborOpt)
                    </td>

                </tr>       



                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ADRate)
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ADRate)
                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ADCostFact)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ADCostFact)
                    </td>

                    <td colspan="1">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ADAutoCost)
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ADAutoCost)
                    </td>
                    <td >

                    </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ADBarcode)
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ADBarcode)
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </table><br /> 
     <table> 
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <fieldset>
                     <legend >Account Type</legend>
                     <br />

                     <table>
                         <tr>
                             <td>
                                 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ADAcctType, "Credit", new { @checked = "checked", id = "Credit", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                                 @Html.Label("Credit", "Credit", new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td>
                                 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ADAcctType, "Debit", new { id = "Debit", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                                 @Html.Label("Debit", "Debit", new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                     </table>
                 </fieldset>
             </td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>
                 <fieldset>
                     <legend >Tax Flags</legend><br />
                     <table>
                         <tr>
                             <td>
                                 @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SalesTA)
                                 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SalesTA, new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                            </td>
                             <td>&nbsp;</td>
                             <td>
                                 @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.TaxAuth3)
                                 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TaxAuth3, new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td>
                                 @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.PST)
                                 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PST, new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                             </td>
                             <td>&nbsp;</td>
                             <td>           
                                 @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.TaxAuth4)
                                 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TaxAuth4, new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td>
                                 @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.TaxAuth5)
                                 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TaxAuth5, new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                     </table>
                 </fieldset>
             </td>
         </tr>
    </table>
        </div>

        <div id="tabs-2">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Cost Cluster Accounts</legend>
                <br />
                <div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CAClusterCredit)
                    @Html.DropDownList("clusterAcct", "[Select]")
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CAClusterCredit)
                </div>
                <br />
                <div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CAClusterDebit)
                    @Html.DropDownList("clusterAcct", "[Select]")
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CAClusterDebit)
                </div>
                <br />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Income Cluster Accounts</legend>
                <br />
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CABilled)
               @Html.DropDownList("clusterAcct", "[Select]")
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Quick Books</legend>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QAClassName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QAClassName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QAClassName)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QACostInventory)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QACostInventory)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QACostInventory)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QACostCredit)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QACostCredit)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QACostCredit)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QACostDebit)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QACostDebit)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QACostDebit)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>AccPac</legend>
                <div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QASegementNo)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QASegementNo)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QASegementNo)
                </div>
                <br />
                <div>

                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.QAExportAcctCode)
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QAExportAcctCode)

                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.QAExportAllSeg)
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QAExportAllSeg)


                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.QAExportAcctCodeShopNo)
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QAExportAcctCodeShopNo)
                </div>

            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-4">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Account Type</legend><br />
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ERAAcctType, "None", new { @checked = "checked", id = "ATNone", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                            @Html.Label("ATNone", "None", new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ERAAcctType, "Body", new { id = "ATBody", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                            @Html.Label("ATBody", "Body", new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ERAAcctType, "Paint", new { id = "ATPaint", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                            @Html.Label("ATPaint", "Paint", new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ERAAcctType, "Frame", new { id = "ATFrame", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                            @Html.Label("ATFrame", "Frame", new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ERAAcctType, "Mechanical", new { id = "ATMechanical", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                            @Html.Label("ATMechanical", "Mechanical", new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ERAAcctType, "Structural", new { id = "ATStructural", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                            @Html.Label("ATStructual", "Structural", new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ERAAcctType, "User 1", new { id = "ATUser1", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                            @Html.Label("ATUser1", "User 1", new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ERAAcctType, "User 2", new { id = "ATUser2", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                            @Html.Label("ATUser2", "User 2", new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ERAAcctType, "User 3", new { id = "ATUser3", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                            @Html.Label("ATUser3", "User 3", new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ERAAcctType, "User 4", new { id = "ATUser4", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                            @Html.Label("ATUser4", "User 4", new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ERAAcctType, "User 5", new { id = "ATUser5", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                            @Html.Label("ATUser5", "User 5", new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ERAAcctType, "User 6", new { id = "ATUser6", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                            @Html.Label("ATUser6", "User 6", new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>ERA GOG Type</legend><br />
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ERAGOGType, "None", new { @checked = "checked", id = "ERANone", @onClick = "ERANoneClick();", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                            @Html.Label("ERANone", "None", new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ERAGOGType, "Frieght", new { id = "ERAFrieght", @onClick = "ERAClick();", @class = "groupsRadio", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                            @Html.Label("ERAFrieght", "Frieght", new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ERAGOGType, "Gas/Oil/Grease", new { id = "ERAGas/Oil/Grease", @onClick = "ERAClick();", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                            @Html.Label("ERAGas/Oil/Grease", "Gas/Oil/Grease", new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ERAGOGType, "PaintMaterials", new { id = "ERAPaintMaterials", @onClick = "ERAClick();", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                            @Html.Label("ERAPaintMaterials", "Paint Materials", new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ERAGOGType, "ShopSupplies", new { id = "ERAShopSupplies", @onClick = "ERAClick();", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                            @Html.Label("ERAShopSupplies", "Shop Supplies", new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ERAGOGCode)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ERAGOGCode, new { @disabled = true })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-5">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Select One or More Tasks(Setup Up as Multiple Accounts in Forecasting)</legend><br />
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.BLU_TEAR)
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BLU_TEAR, new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.BUFF)
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BUFF, new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SUP_APRV)
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SUP_APRV, new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.REASY)
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.REASY, new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.BODY)
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BODY, new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SUBLET)
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SUBLET, new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.FRAME)
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FRAME, new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.MNTBAL)
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MNTBAL, new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.MECH)
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MECH, new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ALIGN)
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ALIGN, new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.A_CUTIN)
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.A_CUTIN, new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.DETAIL)
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DETAIL, new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.B_PREP)
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.B_PREP, new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Q_C)
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Q_C, new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.C_PAINT)
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.C_PAINT, new { style = "padding-right:20px;font-size:small" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>


    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}'
But by using html.raw my whole page gets refreshed. What is the better solution for this,for avoiding to refresh the whole page.

thanks in advance

Comment: you want to stop on form post page refreshing?

Comment: yes @EhsanSajjad when the acctCode exist while showing the popup msg

Comment: you can ``Ajax.BeginForm`` instead of `Html.BeginForm` it will post data via ajax without page refresh

Comment: '@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "AccountCodes", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl },FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "bootstrap-frm" })) 'right now i am using this . what should i change in this ??

Comment: post your complete view in question post then it will be easy to help out

Comment: I tried to use ajax.beginform but the same thing happens my view disappers on the msg popup

Comment: have you include ``jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.js`` file

Comment: when i am using 'jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.js' and click on create nothing happens

Comment: check firebug console is ajax call successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to refresh page just send Ajax call on button click event and and show pop message based on its response.
lets assume you are using jQuery then button ajax call should be something like this -

```
$("#validateButton).click(function(){

  // send ajax call to CheckKey action with key parameter and on success function
  // show popup.
   $.ajax({
      // all ajax code
      success:function(result){
       if(result !="validkey")
       {
        alert("popup);
       }
      }
   });

});
```

and controller action should be something like this.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CheckKey(String key)
    {
       // do here databse operation to check.
       if(key == "foo")
       {
         return Json("Key already present. try for different.");
       }
      else
       {
         return Json("validkey");
       }
}
```

Comment: I am using count here.. so what should i do to return count??

Comment: You can return your count in json result as-  return Json(count); or based on your count you can return any other thing to Json and based on those result you can modify your Ajax success function.

Comment: How do i return my view??

Comment: What is your actual requirement ? you have to pass your message view(html) from controller action ? if you have to pass just   "<script>alert('Account Code already exist');</script>". just pass your message "Account Code already exist" as json string and use it in Success function in script section.